# Copy part of a queue to another queue,or even copy from a queue to an array

Tags: c#

I am attempting to copy part of a queue to another queue.  As a compromise I tried online a way to copy part of a queue to an array.

```
var values = stocks.Select(s => new DateClose() { Date = s.Date.Date, Close = 
s.Close });
var movingAverageQueueAll = new Queue<DateClose>(values);
// take part of the movingAverageQueueAll put in an array
var movingAverageArray = new DateClose[movingAverageQueueAll.Count() -210].Select(h=> new DateClose()).ToArray();
 movingAverageQueueAll.CopyTo(movingAverageArray, 210);
```

The issue is on line "movingAverageQueueAll.CopyTo(movingAverageArray, 210);"

There is not an error but the webpage for the Controller has an internal server error and does not display the data I expect.

Comment: can movingAverageQueueAll.Count() < 210 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code comes after the validation `movingAverageQueueAll.Count() > 210` as you said the issue is in the last line, you may misunderstand the second parameter of [Queue.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2). It is not the starting point in `movingAverageQueueAll` but the one in `movingAverageArray` where the data are copied to. so, your code always copies original collection of data to a smaller array, and ends up with error.

If your intention is to acquire a subset of data after a certain index, then try this. `Skip` and `Take` are LINQ methods.

```
var movingAverageArray = movingAverageQueueAll.Skip(210).Take(movingAverageQueueAll.Count() - 210);
```